# Radio, Dropdown, Check on same line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a radio button, dropdown, and checkbox on the same line for where the second radio button appears.  I am using Bootstrap 4, but I do not need this to look or conform to bootstrap ideals.  Plain looking html is fine.

I thought that `display:inline`, or `display:inline-block` using a `div` around the second radio group should have done it, but the stubborn checkbox remains in the line below, rather than inline.

What I want:

```
   Line 1:  Radio button (Popular)
   Line 2:  Radio button (Order), Dropdown, Checkbox
```

What I have:

```
   Line 1:  Radio button (Popular)
   Line 2:  Radio button (Order), Dropdown
   Line 3:  Checkbox
```

Code below:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input style="height:1em; width:1em;" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="popular" name="abc" checked>Popular
    </label>
</div> 
<div class="form-check">    
    <div style="display:inline-block;">    
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input style="height:1em; width:1em;" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="order" name="abc" checked>Order
        </label>
        <select id="user_tag_dropdown">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
        </select>  
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> All
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using it like this..

```html
 <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input style="height:1em; width:1em;" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="popular" name="abc" checked>Popular
    </label>
</div> 
<div class="form-check">    
    <div style="display:inline-block;">    
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input style="height:1em; width:1em;" type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="order" name="abc" checked>Order
        </label>
        <select id="user_tag_dropdown">
            <option>One</option>
            <option>Two</option>
        </select>  
        <div class="checkbox" style="display: inline">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> All
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```